# catch doesn't work when the API can't be reached

Tags: javascript, api, try-catch

i'm trying to figure out why my catch never happens when the API can't be reached. There is my function below.
To be clear, the function creates a number of elements if the API is reached but should return an error message when it doesn't.
Thanks in advance

```
const itemList = document.querySelector(".item-list");

function displayItems() {
  // Reaching API
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/cameras",{ method: 'GET'} )
  .then((response) =>
    response.json().then((data) => {
        for (let object of data) {
          // Create a card for each data element (Links, name, price and img only)
            const linkID = document.createElement("a");
            const createDiv = document.createElement("div");
            const itemImg = document.createElement("div");
            const details = document.createElement("div");
            //Manage all created elements
            itemList.appendChild(linkID);
            linkID.appendChild(createDiv);
            createDiv.appendChild(itemImg);
            createDiv.appendChild(details);
            //Give a class to each created element
            createDiv.classList.add("item");
            itemImg.classList.add("item__photo");
            details.classList.add("item__details");
            //Set up values inside each of the previous elements
            linkID.setAttribute('href', './Pages/product.html'+ '?id=' + object._id)
            itemImg.innerHTML = `<img src="${object.imageUrl}" alt="${object.name}"/>`;
            details.innerHTML = `<h3>${object.name}</h3>` + `<span>${object.price/100} € </span>`;
          }
      })
      .catch (() => {
        itemList.innerHTML = "Nous n'avons pas pu afficher de produits, revenez ultérieurement";
      })
  );
}
displayItems();
```

Comment: The `catch()` is chainign the `json()`, it will be use if body parsing fails; chaining to the `fetch().then(r=>r.json().then()).catch(...)`

Comment: You're only `.catch()`ing error from the `response.json()` promise (or its `then` handler), but not on the promise returned by `fetch()` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer .then and .catch should have been parallel but we had .catch for there only for inner .then so after pulling it and making it for outer .catch, it is working. See the corrected code.

```
const itemList = document.querySelector(".item-list");

function displayItems() {
  // Reaching API
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/cameras",{ method: 'GET'} )
  .then((response) =>
    response.json().then((data) => {
        for (let object of data) {
          // Create a card for each data element (Links, name, price and img only)
            const linkID = document.createElement("a");
            const createDiv = document.createElement("div");
            const itemImg = document.createElement("div");
            const details = document.createElement("div");
            //Manage all created elements
            itemList.appendChild(linkID);
            linkID.appendChild(createDiv);
            createDiv.appendChild(itemImg);
            createDiv.appendChild(details);
            //Give a class to each created element
            createDiv.classList.add("item");
            itemImg.classList.add("item__photo");
            details.classList.add("item__details");
            //Set up values inside each of the previous elements
            linkID.setAttribute('href', './Pages/product.html'+ '?id=' + object._id)
            itemImg.innerHTML = `<img src="${object.imageUrl}" alt="${object.name}"/>`;
            details.innerHTML = `<h3>${object.name}</h3>` + `<span>${object.price/100} € </span>`;
          }
      }))
  .catch (() => {
        itemList.innerHTML = "Nous n'avons pas pu afficher de produits, revenez ultérieurement";
      });
}
displayItems();
```

Comment: Now this fails to show an error message when the API is reachable but does return an error.

Comment: I mean both the catch would be necessary given the use case but I just corrected it out to see what's wrong,

Comment: With proper promise chaining, only a single handler would be necessary to catch both errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's now working as planned. Will need to edit all my catch on other functions because they are following the same model